# convert a string to a map or list in tcl

Tags: list, tcl

I've a command output as something below this is an example

```
card-1-1-1   4   -Number  1  -type  Eth  -config        -GEPorts 4
card-1-3-1   3   -Number  2  -type  Eth  -config   Yes  -GEPorts 3
```

I need this to be converted into a list like

```
card-1-1-1   4
-Number  1  
-type  Eth  
-config  if_empty_insert_null  
-GEPorts 4
card-1-3-1   3   
-Number  2  
-type  Eth  
-config   Yes  
-GEPorts 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if it wasn't for the fact that you've got some options that are *sometimes* missing associated values, this would be pretty much trivial. As it is, we need to be more careful. The main tricky bits are using `regexp -all -inline` to parse to a Tcl list and using a `for` loop to iterate over everything when detecting absent parameters.

```
# Process each line
foreach row [split $inputData "\n"] {
    # If there's a comment syntax or blank lines are allowed, you handle them here

    # Safely convert to a Tcl list
    set words [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $row]

    # First two words are used "as is"
    set pairs [lrange $words 0 1]

    # Can't use foreach here; non-constant step size prevents it
    for {set i 2} {$i < [llength $words]} {incr i} {
        set paramName [lindex $words $i]
        set next [lindex $words [expr {$i + 1}]]

        # Set the default for if the option is value-less
        set parameter "if_empty_insert_null"

        # Look for a value; slightly complex as I'm allowing for negative numbers
        if {$next ne "" && ![regexp {^-[a-zA-Z]} $next]} {
            set parameter $next
            incr i
        }

        # Now we can update the list as we know the pair of values to add
        lappend pairs $paramName $parameter
    }

    # Now print everything out; we can use foreach for this as we're guaranteed to
    # have an even number of values
    foreach {a b} $pairs {
        # Do more complex formatting if you want
        puts "$a $b"
    }
}
```